# Extract Date and Hour from NSDate - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nsdatecomponents

I have `dateString` with this format `"mm/dd/yyyy '-' HH:mm"`.
I want to extract the date in string and hour in string.
I've tried the following code but this return a wrong date:

```
- (void) extractDate: (NSString *)dateString intoHour: (NSString *)hourLabel and: (NSString*)dateLabel {
    NSDateFormatter *formatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"mm/dd/yyyy '-' HH:mm"];
    NSData *date = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];

    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit fromDate:date];

    hourLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu:%lu", [components hour], [components minute]];
    dateLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu/%lu/%lu", [components day], [components month], [components year]];
}
```

Exemple String: `"05/01/2015 - 11:15"`

Result: date: `1/1/2015`, time: `11:15`
and also how can I maintain this date format `dd/mm/yyyy`, I mean when the day is `1`, it shows `01`

Comment: `MM` for the month, else wise it's minutes (as you used it already).
NSNumberFormatter can use leading zero if needed. Or you can just use a `NSDateFormatter` from the date you got, instead of use `NSDateComponents`: `[formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"]; dateLabel = [formatter stringFromDate:date]; [formatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"]; hourLabel = [formatter stringFromDate:date];` By the way `hourLabel`/`dateLabel` as `NSString` and not `UILabel` is quite a misleading var naming.

Comment: You should use `NSDateFormatter` to do it. But for your interest, use `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d", [components day]]` would do the job for you,

Comment: How to use  `NSDateFormatter` to get each part in a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested but:

`MM` for the month. Not `mm` which is minutes.

You already have a `NSDateFormatter` so why not use it again instead of `NSDateComponents` and `NSString` formats?

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy '-' HH:mm"];
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];

//Now you have the correct date. So we'll use the NSDateFormatter to transform NSDate (date) into NSString according to the format we need.

[formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
dateLabel = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
hourLabel = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
```

`hourLabel`/`dateLabel` as `NSString` and not `UILabel` is quite a misleading var naming.